# How can I implement CRUD integration between Google Sheets and Zoho CRM leads module?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio, zoho

Summed up, I'm seeking to replicate the Zoho leads funnel in Google Data Studio. When complete, a lead should move from one stage to another within Google Data Studio in real time or once per day as it is updated in Zoho CRM.

I currently have each stage in the funnel broken out as an individual spreadsheet which receives data from Zoho Flow when new leads are created but I have not found a way to update Google sheets as a lead progresses down the funnel.

I have tried various Zoho Flows, a blended data approach through Google Data Studio, scheduling a Zoho report, programmatically using Sheets and Zoho API, and a workflow using Zoho webhooks all with no luck.

Thanks for any advice folks can give!

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you can configure a trigger as per your choice in Zoho CRM and then you can use Fetch Row action and connect it to Update row action in Google sheets. Please refer to the below image-

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Will give this a try now.

Comment: thanks for the tip! In the `fetch row` portion, how do I select a particular row based on an update to lead status? Right now I am using the `Lead ID` field with a ${trigger.id} value but with limited success.